# Syntax to pass dynamic variables to include_tasks along with with_item in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Executing parent.yml which in turn calls child.yml playbook for execution with dynamic variables.

Variables from parent.yml aren`t interpolated inside child.yml playbook. Correct me if I am using correct syntax?

Parent.yml

```
- name: Main playbook to call MySQL backup
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - include_task: child.yml
    vars:
      var1: "{{ item.name }}"
      var2: "{{ item.db_name }}"
    with_items:
       - { name: '10.10.10.01', db_name: 'prod1' }
       - { name: '10.10.10.02', db_name: 'prod2' }
```

child.yml (Takes mysqldump from managed DB)

```
- name: MySQL dump
  hosts: localhost
  #gather_facts: no
  #vars:
  #      v1: "{{ var1 }}"
  #      v2: "{{ var2 }}"

  tasks:
  - name: Executing the shell script
    shell: 'mysqldump -h "{{ var1 }}" -u"ansi" -p"*****" "{{ var2 }}"| gzip > /tmp/mysql_dump/"{{ var2 }}"_`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`.gz'
```

fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"reason": "no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ansible/playbooks/DBpatch/Linux/child.yml': line 1, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: MySQL dump\n  ^ here\n"}

Answer (score 0):

include_task expects a list of tasks but you give it a complete playbook.
Child.yml should only contain what is currently below the line "tasks:".
See also https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html

Comment: thank you, I did some work around by using a dictionary to work in same playbook